# Can I pay with my phone if I switch to Cyanogenmod?

Tags: sim-card, nfc, oneplus-3

I own an `Oneplus 3` and a NFC sim card. In order to use the banking payment app of my bank (`Rabobank Wallet`: https://www.rabowallet.nl/ / Netherlands) I need a phone with android supporting `open mobile api` as far as I understood. I read online that Oxygen OS does not have support for OMA, but Cm does. Will flashing CM make me able to pay with the Rabo Wallet app?

### Bonus question:

Only very expensive providers support NFC payment in their sim card. Can I switch provider, (which has no NFC sim) place it's sim in slot #1 en the NFC sim (without data plan) in slot #2 and pay with the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes flashing Cyanogenmod will enable you to pay using your banking app.
 Cyanogenmod does have support for the Open Mobile API.

The Second approach however will be a bit tricky to do as I have not tried that. But I think its worth giving a try ! 
If it doesn't works, the first option will do just fine!.

PS : I like Cyanogenmod more than Oxygen OS, I suggest you that you use it as your daily driver.

Comment: Be aware CyanogenMod, but not CyanogenOS, has root built in by default... some banking, payment, and financial apps will not work if the device is rooted or has even just has su installed.

Comment: @acejavelin Cyanogenmod's root access is disabled by default ! You can gain root access through flashing the SuperSu zip or by pushing via adb. However it also has a default root privilege which can be enabled in settings.

Comment: Bonus question is because of the very expensive plan that comes with the nfc sim-card. So I want to use it without keeping the plan.

Comment: @Thomas you can choose which SIM card you use to connect to Internet. Also, if your bank app won't work, try Xposed and http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.devadvance.rootcloak2